# How to write a namespace which exposes common namespaces for avoiding multiple using statements in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, refactoring

Following is my code for a .NET Core app.

**CommonSpace.cs**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace CommonSpace
{
    class CommonSpace
    {
        //dummy class
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using CommonSpace;


namespace BackToBasicsApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            /*
            code which uses System.IO, System.Text.RegularExpressions from CommonSpace goes here
            */

        }
    }
}
```

How do i make use of classes exposed by the System.IO, System.Text.RegularExpressions namespaces from CommonSpace.
This question struck me while refactoring some of my code and i saw a very long list of using statements at the top of my classes.
This is a very basic question so forgive me BackToBasicness...;)

Here is my revised **CommonSpace.cs**

```
using System;

namespace CommonSpace
{
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
}
```

This still dosen't work :(

Comment: As a side note to your question. [Read this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/) from one of the most important developers of the C# language

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is and what you are trying to achieve. Is there a lot of code bloat? Generally if you find you have too many using in one file then you can probably separate some responsibilities. But I wouldn't go hacking at code just because there are too many using statements. I'd look at the actual code structure to decide.

Comment: If you are using visual studio, you can hit ctrl + . and it will remove unused using statements.  Besides that,  Tamirs statement is spot on.

Comment: @Steve thanks for the pointer but,the class was just for filling up space and is a dummy.I've changed the CommonSpace.cs though :)

Comment: @Tamir, You are very correct about that, I would really love to restructure the multiple usings, but i want to wrap my multiple usings as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i make use of classes exposed by the System.IO, System.Text.RegularExpressions namespaces from CommonSpace.

You can't: the language specification is that `using` statements have a scope limited to the compilation unit or namespace body in which they are declared. In practice this means they are never visible outside the file where the declaration is, and in the case of your `CommonSpace` they are scoped to within the curly braces.

[More details in the C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces)

There is a good reason for this: if you want to know which namespace the class in a piece of code is using, it is right there in the file. There would be no end of problems with name clashes if all the using directives from elsewhere were leaking into your namespace.

If you really have too many using directives in your file, then your design is probably wrong, you should split your classes into smaller units.